# ASUS Motherboard drivers for windows server 2022

Tags: drivers, motherboard, compatibility, windows-server-2022

I have an asus z790-plus TUF Gaming Wifi D5 Intel LGA 1700 ATX MotherBoard.
I know it says officially that is supports windows 10 and 11.
But I need to install windows server 2022 and the drivers are not working. isn't the kernel build similarly that such things should not be an issue? I still have issues with the network, wifi, and sound drivers only

Comment: Did you get the drivers from [here](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/tuf-gaming/tuf-gaming-z790-plus-wifi/helpdesk_download/?model2Name=TUF-GAMING-Z790-PLUS-WIFI)?

Comment: yes I did, the installers don't work. and manually installing the drivers didn't give the intended result

Comment: Strange, Windows Server 2022 should use the same platform and drivers as Windows 11. Did you also update the BIOS? Note: You should get the drivers from the manufacturer, for example Realtek for audio.

Comment: hmmm. that's a good Idea. I'll try that tomorrow. thanks

Comment: As an update should anyone need it. I didn't really get all the drivers to work. just made it work with what I had. for example I just ditched the idea of using wifi. cable was the way to go